# Add loop function on divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
function houseScroll() {
    var house = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
    randClass = house[Math.floor(Math.random() * house.length)];
    $('#houses').stop().animate({
        'left': -$(this).outerWidth(true)
    }, 100000, 'linear');
    if (('#house div:first-child').outerWidth(true)) {
        $('#houses div:last').after('<div class="item current-last ' + randClass + '"></div>');
    }
}
```

I want when out of browser my first item, add a new item to last. Tried `if` but not working.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You missed $ in if condition, I guess, it should be if ($('#house div:first-child').outerWidth(true)) { instead

Comment: HTML ? Can you create a fiddle ?